# PHP 7.4 and MySQL Connections

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I realized that mysqli is indeed loading and communicating with PHP (even though the extension is still remarked out in php.ini) so the problem I've been having seems to relate to a change in PHP's version 7.4 in the way it connects to the database.

My local development databases use a simple password and I'm not sure what I need to do get it working again while still maintaining compatibility with the older MySQL 5.X on the live server but my sites use this function to connect. I did review [another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231143/does-mysqli-have-support-for-caching-sha2-password-in-php-7-4) about it and tried the test code provided there but still could not connect. In the end this is what needs to be changed as all my sites share it so what is needed?

```
function dbConn($DBname) {
    global $DBhost;
    global $DBusername;
    global $DBpass;
    $dbconn = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBusername, $DBpass, $DBname);
    mysqli_set_charset($dbconn,"UTF8");
    return $dbconn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so
```

Comment: Thank you and welcome! That seems to give full read/write to Owner, Group and Others when only Owner should have read/write. In any event, it made no difference and the file still does not load. I should add that the issue seems to be with any *.so*, not just the example I used.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question as I realized the problem is elsewhere. I'm still not sure how PHP 7.4 finds the extensions since the calls to them are all remarked out in both of the two php.ini files but it does indeed load them somehow.